# sphinx config || config/sphinx.yml

Tags: yaml, sphinx, config, thinking-sphinx

my sphinx configuration is:

```
================================ config/sphinx.yml
development:
  bin_path: "/usr/local/bin"
  searchd_binary_name: searchd
  indexer_binary_name: indexer
```

but everytime i run a `rake ts:index`

```
Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name

For more information, read the documentation:
For more information, read the documentation:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html
Generating Configuration to config/development.sphinx.conf
Sphinx 2.0.1-beta (r2792)
Copyright (c) 2001-2011, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2011, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file 'config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'post_core'...
collected 2 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 2 docs, 675 bytes
total 0.006 sec, 110510 bytes/sec, 327.43 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'post'...
total 6 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 12 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=19438).
Generating Configuration to config/development.sphinx.conf
Sphinx 2.0.1-beta (r2792)
Copyright (c) 2001-2011, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2011, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file 'config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'post_core'...
collected 2 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 2 docs, 675 bytes
total 0.006 sec, 105567 bytes/sec, 312.79 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'post'...
total 6 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 12 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=19438).
```

So what's the problem? Why does the rake output that it cant find it even though its installed?

Answer (score 3):

The warning from Thinking Sphinx could definitely be clearer... the problem is very likely to be how old your version of Thinking Sphinx is. Older TS versions don't know about Sphinx 2.0.x - so I'd recommend updating to the latest version of Thinking Sphinx (either 1.4.6 for Rails 1.2 and 2.x, or 2.0.5 for Rails 3).

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that help to solve this problem. First, as Pat says, it is useful to update the Thinking Sphinx plugin or gem to the latest version (either 1.4.x for Rails 2, or 2.0.x for Rails 3). Second it helps sometimes to [specify the version of Sphinx](http://freelancing-gods.com/posts/searching_with_sphinx_on_heroku) in the configuration file (you can find it out by calling "indexer"), especially if Sphinx is running on a remote server and Thinking Sphinx does not have access to Sphinx locally:

```
production:
  ..
  version: 2.0.4  # <------- Version of Sphinx on remote server 192.168.1.10
  port: 9312 
  address: 192.168.1.10
  ..
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and looked everywhere for an answer without any resolution.

The trick that worked for me was to install older version of sphinx. v .9 instead of the latest beta.

Using the latest Thinking-Sphinx with this version of sphinx resolved the issue.